# CKEditor doesnt show in edit mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I instaled CKEditor, it loads fine in new form but in edit i need to refresh the page in order to show ckeditor. There is section on Initialize CKEditor in Javascript file on github, which i dont know how to do. Maybe thats why. I included //= require ckeditor-jquery in application.js file though.

my form partial is

```
 <%= simple_form_for @message, html: { multipart: true }  do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :title, label: "Message Title"  %>
      <%= f.input :description, label: "Short Description" %>



      <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'ckeditor' %>
<%= f.button :submit, style: "margin-bottom: 80px" %>
<% end %>
```

and here is my edit

```
<h1>Edit Message</h1>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

And on my show page, edited text shows as html(including html tags) and i want to show it as rich edited text, not html.

```
<p class="message-desc"><%= @message.content %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the nature of turbolinks? Try to disable turbolinks in the corresponding field.

```
<div data-no-turbolink>
  <%= f.text_area :content, :class => 'ckeditor' %>
</div>
```